# Pushing to array leads to infinite loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is a jsfiddle with this problem, but please be careful as it contains the endless loop and makes the browser tab lag and eventually freeze if you open the console: https://jsfiddle.net/evx1j6yf/1/

Arrays:

```
days: [
  "monday",
  "tuesday",
  "wednesday",
  "thursday",
  "friday",
  "saturday"
],

openingDays: []
```

Template:

```
{% for day in days %}
    {[ formatDays(day) ]}
{% endfor %}
```

**formatDays:**

```
 formatDays(day) {
     message = translateDays(day);
     openingDays.push(message);
 }
```

**What I expected:** My second array should be filled with a copy of the days.
**What I got:** an endless loop where after the last day, it just repeats itself ad infinitum.

Console.log:

```
["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", ...
```

Comment: print message in formatDays function and check how many times formatDays  function is calling

Comment: @VijayKrishna It is called an infinte amount of time, but I do not understand why. This one  part in the template next to the translateDays function is the only occurence, and translateDays prints 6 times as expected. If I remove the Array.push from formatDays, it also prints 6 times.

Comment: @VijayKrishna I have added a small jsfiddle showing the problem (careful, the endless loop might make the browser lag): https://jsfiddle.net/evx1j6yf/1/

Comment: whenever you call `formatDays` it causes a re-render as the data being displayed in the template is being changed. Since `formatDays` is a method and used directly in the template using `{{}}` it is called on every re-render. Hence the infinite loop. What exactly is the usecase you are trying to obtain? I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evx1j6yf/34/). Is this what you want?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, I understand the problem now thanks to your explanation and your example is good, I can adjust it for my needs. If you copy your comment to an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **What i got**: an endless loop where after the last day, it just repeats itself ad infinitum.

Whenever you call `formatDays` it causes a re-render as the data being displayed in the template is being changed. Since `formatDays` is a method and used directly in the template using `{{}}` it is called on every re-render. Hence the infinite loop.

> **What I expected**: My second array should be filled with a copy of the days.

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evx1j6yf/34/).